# $\prod$ and factorial

Tags: factorial

$\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(j-i+1)$ is $=$ to $(j+1)!$ or $\le$?
I think it is $=$, but if it's not, please put an explanation.

Comment: Yes, it is equal to that (case $j=0$ needs special attention, though).

Comment: Expand the product what do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(j-i+1)=(j+1)\cdot j\cdot (j-1)\cdots 3\cdot 2=(j+1)!
$$

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
\prod_{i=0}^{j-1} (j-i+1) & = (j+1)\cdot j\cdot (j-1)\cdots(j-(j-2)+1)\cdot (j-(j-1)+1)\\
& = 2\cdots (j+1)=(j+1)!
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Set $j-i+1=t$

$i=0\implies t=j+1$

$i=j-1\implies t=?$

$$\prod_{i=0}^{j-1}(j-i+1)=\prod_{t=j+1}^2t=\prod_{t=2}^{j+1}t=?$$